# How do I execute the app right after installation ... with arguments?

Tags: nsis

My installation EXE should unzip itself in a temp folder, then execute an app therein (with passing args), return and delete the temp folder again.
How do I write the nsi script?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are trying to create a portable application. Portable applications are always better when the original author adds support for it because it can handle registry and other configuration files correctly.

If you still want to create a launcher application you can do something like this:

```
OutFile "MyLauncher.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel User
SilentInstall Silent
SetCompressor LZMA

!include FileFunc.nsh
!insertmacro GetParameters

Section
${GetParameters} $1
InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File "c:\myfiles\MyApp.exe"
File /r "c:\myfiles\otherfiles\*.*" ; If you need to include other files required by the application
ExecWait '"$PluginsDir\MyApp.exe" /param1 "pa ra m2" /param3 $1' $0 ; $1 contains the parameters passed to your launcher, remove it if you don't want to pass those arguments
SetErrorLevel $0
SetOutPath $Temp ; Don't lock $PluginsDir so it can be deleted automatically by the installer
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
The required nsi script skeleton should look like this:

```
# The name of the installer (arbitrary)
Name "hello"

# The name of the installation file
OutFile "hello.exe"

# where put the installation - other options would be $TEMP, etc.
InstallDir $DESKTOP

RequestExecutionLevel user         # no Windows UAC popup please!
SilentInstall silent               # completely silent install
SetCompressor /SOLID /FINAL lzma   # max compression for inst. file

# The stuff to install
Section ""
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR              # where to install (overwritable by user!)
  File /r D:\...\...               # where the install material lives
SectionEnd

# this function auto-runs after installation is fine
Function .onInstSuccess
  # parameter are passed through via $CMDLINE
  ExecWait '"$OUTDIR\hello.dist\hello.exe" $CMDLINE'
  RMDir /r "$OUTDIR\hello.dist"    # remove install folder again
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: You should probably not use $DESKTOP as a temporary directory.